# JPA - CriteriaQuery generates a wrong SQL

Tags: jpa

**Table Municipio:**

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "Chave")
private Integer chave;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 40)
@Column(name = "Nome")
private String nome;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "Cep")
private int cep;
@JoinColumn(name = "Uf", referencedColumnName = "Chave")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Uf uf;
```

**Table Uf:**

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 2)
@Column(name = "Chave")
private String chave;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "Nome")
private String nome;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "uf")
private Collection<Municipio> municipioCollection;
```

**Lazy Bean:**

```
private Query createQuery(Class type, boolean count, Map<String, Object> filters, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteria = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery query = criteria.createQuery((count ? Long.class : type));
    Root from = query.from(type);

    query.select((count ? criteria.count(from) : from));

    List filter = new ArrayList();  
    for (String filterProperty : filters.keySet()) {
        String filterValue = (String) filters.get(filterProperty);
        Expression literal = criteria.literal((String) filterValue);
        filter.add(criteria.like(from.get(filterProperty), literal));
    }
    query.where((Predicate[]) filter.toArray(new Predicate[filter.size()]));  

    if (!count) {
        if (multiSortMeta != null) {
            List<Order> order = new ArrayList();
            for (SortMeta sm : multiSortMeta) {
                if (!sm.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.DESCENDING)) {
                    order.add(criteria.asc(from.get(sm.getSortField())));
                } else {
                    order.add(criteria.desc(from.get(sm.getSortField())));
                }
            }
            query.orderBy(order);
        }
    }

    return em.createQuery(query);
}
```

Filtering column without relationship (Nome). That's right!

*SQL*:

```
SELECT COUNT(Chave) FROM Municipio WHERE Nome LIKE ?
```

Filtering column with relationship (Uf). That's wrong!

The field name does not appear in the *WHERE* clause.

*SQL*:

```
SELECT COUNT(t0.Chave) FROM Municipio t0, Uf t1 WHERE ( LIKE ? AND (t1.Chave = t0.Uf))
```

Generating the following error:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.
```

What Can I do?

Comment: The `CriteriaQuery` generates the wrong _SQL_.

Comment: A word of caution to you, your declaration of a ManyToOne and a OneToMany in those related beans will give you a circular reference.  This might be a problem for you in the future.